# « connu pour » ou « connu comme »

Tags: usage, prépositions

J'ai les questions suivantes :

1. Est-ce qu'on dit « connu pour » ou « connu comme » ?
2. Le mot qui vient après « connu pour » ou « connu comme » est-il un adjectif ?

Exemples :

> Barak Obama est plus connu pour le président américain.
>
> Elvis Presley est plus connu comme chanteur.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lorsque l'on parle du "poste" occupé, du rôle social (qui), on utilise "connu comme" :

> Bill Clinton est plus connu comme président américain
>
> Elvis Presley est plus connu comme chanteur

On pourrait remplacer "comme" par "en tant que", je trouve même ça plus agréable à l'oreille.

Lorsque l'on parle de l'action/de la production (quoi), on utilise "connu pour" :

> Bill Clinton est plus connu pour l'affaire Lewinsky
>
> Bill Clinton est plus connu pour ses talents de saxophoniste
>
> Elvis Presley est plus connu pour ses films

Evidemment, au final le sens reste similaire et il se peut qu'il existe des contre-exemples auxquels je ne pense pas dans l'immédiat.

Quant à ta deuxième question, je ne vois aucune raison de considérer cela comme un adjectif, président reste un nom.